# How to read random row from column 1 thet is equal with random row from column 2 IN Microsoft SQL SERVER 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have 3 columns

1. column Mark1
2. column Transition
3. column Mark2

```
    Mark1    Transition   Mark2
    1            a           2
    2            b           3
    1            a           4
    4            c           5
```

The result I want to get:

- The result of Mark2 where transition is equal to "a" and mark1 is equal to "1"
- then the result of Mark2 where transition is equal to "b" and first row of Mark2 is equal to second row of Mark1

Or the result:

```
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this isnt pretty but it does what i think you have asked for.

The reason for the cte's is to make the sql more legible.

```
with t1a as
    (select * 
    from tablea a
    where a.mark1 = 1
    and a.transition = 'a'),
t2b as
    (select * 
    from tablea a
    where a.mark1 = 2
    and a.transition = 'b')
select t1a.mark2 
from t1a
where mark2 in (select mark1 from t2b)
union 
select t2b.mark2
from t2b
```

Hopefully i havent misunderstood your request.